# R: split a string in a dataframe column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, strsplit

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns contains strings. I'd like to split that strings, separated by a dot, and keep always the first part.

This would be my dataframe:

```
                                             State
1             This is my string. I do not want this
2   This is other string. I do not want this either
```

I'd like to obtain this:

```
                   State
1      This is my string
2   This is other string
```

I've tried with this but it's now working:

```
df = df >%> dplyr::mutate(State= str_split(State,".")[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df
                                            State
1           This is my string. I do not want this
2 This is other string. I do not want this either
df %>% mutate(State = str_remove(State, '\\..*'))
                 State
1    This is my string
2 This is other string
```